# After OSX 10.8 upgrade postgres can not connect to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

After a recent upgrade to Mountain Lion, I've run into problems with my brewed postgres install.

```
$ rake db:create
>rake db:migratecould not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After searching around the interwebs, I haven't yet found a solution to this issue.

I have found a suggested steps to help identify the problem but after following these, I'm not sure how to understand the results or what to do next. Can anyone help?

```
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
>pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
>server starting


$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
>pg_ctl: could not send stop signal (PID: 865): No such process


$ pg_ctl status                                                                
>pg_ctl: no server running


$ ps auxw | grep post 
>myuser   19037   2.6  7.7  4388248 324520   ??  S     7:30AM  19:06.02 /Applications/Postbox.app/Contents/MacOS/postbox-bin -psn_0_917728
>myuser   54897   0.1  0.0  2432768    464 s000  R+    1:47PM   0:00.01 grep post


$ cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
>FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
>HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 821) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

Happy to provide any additional info that may be useful.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://gist.github.com/1877457 let me know.

Comment: ok, this may be promising. kill strangely returned failed: no such process. stop also returned could not send stop signal (PID: xxx): No such process. the final option gave FATAL: data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has wrong ownership which i suspect may be important, but I'm not sure how this is supposed to behave. Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

try removing:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

This once worked for me.

Comment: thanks dillon, already tried it. didn't work :) Could you explain your steps in more detail. e.g. stopped DB, deleted, restart...?